# Problema con loop en Wordpress y WPML

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo un loop para recoger los artículos que tienen marcada una casilla (que les añado con Custom fields). Todo funciona correctamente en el idioma por defecto, castellano, pero cuando traduzco el producto a inglés no me aparece la misma ventana que en castellano, me aparece la la pantalla dividida en dos, a la izquierda la versión en español y a la derecha la versión en inglés.

Me aseguro de que el valor para esa casilla que determina si el producto aparece o no sea el mismo (en customs fields es un boolean true/false y aquí aparece como 1/0) en la versión inglesa pero siguen sin aparecerme y ya no se que más hacer... todo me va perfecto en castellano pero no me coge ningún artículo en inglés pese a que tengan ese valor... ¿puede ser que cambie el nombre del meta en el segundo idioma y por eso no pille nada el loop?

Estos son los argumentos del loop (la meta "visible" es la que determina si tiene que aparecer o no):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key'=> 'visible',
    'meta_value'=> true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby'=> 'date'
);
```

Usando Wordpress 4.7.4 / WPML 3.7.0 / ACF 4.4.11

Comment: Estás usando ajax?

Comment: No en mi parte, el tema evidentemente si...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Puedes modificar tu pregunta con las versiones de Wordpres, WPML y ACF que estas usando?

Aquí tienes como usar los ACF con WPML: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/multilingual-custom-fields/

Yo uso la versión pro y con lo que dice ahí nunca me ha dado problemas.

Si no lo estas haciendo así, puede que ese valor solo exista en la parte de "español" y no en los demás idiomas.

Comment: Añadida esa info. Voy a echarle un ojo a lo que me pasas a ver si estoy pasando algo por alto.

Gracias.